# wifi-menu not working; during installation of arch linux no wifi interface is showing in iwconfig

Tags: networking, arch-linux, wifi

Output of `iwconfig`:

```
lo: no wireless extensions
enp9s0: no wireless extensions
```

Output of `lspci | grep Network`

```
0c:00.0 Network controller:  Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY (rev 01)
```

Comment: Anyone know how to connect to wifi during arch installation

Comment: Wifi-menu not working

Comment: iwconfig not showing any wireless interface

Comment: Dont have any ethernet connection completely rely on wifi hotspot

Comment: would be nice to know what "some status" is. Also you want to nicely format the output. Click "help" to find out how.

Answer (score 2):

Many Broadcom wireless adapters require proprietary firmware not included with the Archiso. It is going to be easiest to complete the installation with an Ethernet cable connected if you can manage that, but make sure to install the appropriate [firmware package from the AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/?K=broadcom) when you are installing Arch.

Probably [`b43-firmware`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/b43-firmware/)<sup>AUR</sup> or [`b43-firmware-classic`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/b43-firmware-classic/)<sup>AUR</sup>  is needed.

See the [kernel wireless wiki](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43) for details on identifying which firmware you need.

Otherwise, if Ethernet is not an option, you will need to either [makepkg](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Makepkg) on another system or copy and install the firmware into the Archiso environment [manually](http://linuxwireless.sipsolutions.net/en/users/Drivers/b43/#Other_distributions_not_mentioned_above).

---

If you are relying on a WiFi hotspot from your smart phone you could try using USB tethering from [Android](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Android_tethering) or [iOS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/IPhone_tethering) instead. This will create an Ethernet interface and allow accessing the smart phone's data connection.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to available Wifi network using Network manager.

1. Is Network Manager installed? You install it during the installation of Arch Linux. If not, install it. If you don't have an Ethernet connection, it won't help you.

   ```
   pacman -S wpa_supplicant wireless_tools networkmanager
   ```
2. Enable the Network Manager.

   ```
   systemctl enable NetworkManager
   ```
3. Start Network Manager.

   ```
   systemctl start NetworkManager
   ```
4. Reboot.

   ```
   reboot
   ```
5. List nearby networks.

   ```
   nmcli device wifi list
   ```
6. You should be able to see a list of available networks nearby. Connect to a nearby network. SSID - Name of Wifi Network. SSID_password - Password of Wifi Network.

   ```
   nmcli device wifi connect SSID password SSID_password
   ```

Src : https://linuxhint.com/arch_linux_network_manager/